# AWS Redshift: COPY command fails with 'Role needs to be owned by the same account with cluster'

Tags: redshift

I have a problem with `COPY` in redshift - it's the first time I use it, so probably a beginner's error.

I have uploaded a CSV file to S3 and created the matching table in redshift - I tried the following with various ARNs that seemed likely, but always with the result:

```
copy game_action (game_id,user_id,game_instance_id,type,amount,currency,created_timestamp,game_action_id)
from 's3://some.bucket.name/data_file.csv'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/core/administrator'
csv;
ERROR:  Invalid IAM Role ARN: arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/core/administrator. Role needs to be owned by the same account with cluster
DETAIL:
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Invalid IAM Role ARN: arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/core/administrator. Role needs to be owned by the same account with cluster
  code:      30000
  context:
  query:     2007181
  location:  xen_aws_credentials_mgr.cpp:392
  process:   padbmaster [pid=2901]
  -----------------------------------------------
```

I have no idea what that means, TBH, even less how to fix it. Can someone guide me on the right way?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using access_key_id and secret_access_key instead iam_role

i.e: copy db_table from 's3://bucket_name/s3_file_name' access_key_id 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX' secret_access_key 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY' csv;